# SQL Server not initating a DB on docker deployment

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I know this has been covered multiple times, but I still cannot execute an SQL script on docker deployment.
docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  mssql:
    build: ./docker/mssql
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Welcome@toSQL2022
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mssql/db-data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./docker/mssql/scripts:/var/opt/mssql/scripts
    networks:
      - supernet
   
networks:
  supernet: {}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU15-ubuntu-20.04

COPY ./create-from-mdf.sql .
EXPOSE 1433
 #tried this: CMD ["/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-i", "create-from-mdf.sql", "-S", "localhost", "-U", "SA", "-P" "Welcome@toSQL2022"]
 #tried this: CMD  sleep 30 && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U sa -P Welcome@toSQL2022 -i create-from-mdf.sql#
CMD  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U sa -P Welcome@toSQL2022 -i create-from-mdf.sql
```

I get this error:

```
db       | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
db       | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
db       | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
db exited with code 1
```

However, if I connect to container via CLI the same command gets executed succefully:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U sa -P Welcome@toSQL2022 -i create-from-mdf.sql
```

Comment: You're correct, it seems like this topic has been topic has been discussed so many times it's hard to believe that the solution still evades even a basic Google search. While the Docker container starts immediately the SQL Server service inside it does not. It takes time (sometimes tens of seconds) for the SQL Server service to validate database files, roll forward any incomplete transactions and upgrade them to the latest file format revisions before it opens a listening port to accept incoming connections.

Comment: For an example showing how to wait for SQL Server to start before creating/initializing databases see [twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) by way of [Configure and customize SQL Server Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure).

Comment: @alwayslearning are you saying that 30 sec sleep in CMD ( and I tried 90 as well) is different to having it in entry point? 90 seconds is not enough?

Comment: Yes, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` are different Dockerfile settings. If you `docker run --name sql2019 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU15-ubuntu-20.04` and then `docker inspect sql2019` you'll see that you're overriding the image's built-in `"Cmd": [ "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" ]` which means the SQL Server service is no longer configured to start.